# No puedo imprimir un dato que pertenece a otra tabla

Tags: laravel, foreach, tablas

Mi problema surge dentro de un foreach en una vista que incluye una relación entre 2 tablas. La tabla de pedidos y productos. En la tabla de pedidos uno puede ver cuáles productos fueron seleccionados y lo que intento realizar es mostrar los datos (productos) seleccionados a la tabla de "pedidos". No tengo error en insertar, sólo en la parte de mostrar dichos datos, puedo mostrar el id pero no es lo que deseo hacer.

Vista:

```
    @slot('display')
        @foreach($pedidos as $pedido)
            <div class="display-outdated-data" data-products="">
                <span> {{ $pedido->miembro }} </span>
                <span> {{ $pedido->grupo->nombre }} </span>
                <span> {{ $pedido->productos->producto }} </span>
                <span> {{ $pedido->cantidad }} </span>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <a href="" onclick="return confirm('Este registro se borrará, porfavor confirma')" class="delete-btn">X</a>
                    </div> <!-- Actions END -->
            </div> <!-- Display data END -->
        @endforeach
    @endslot
```

Miembro = miembro, Grupo = grupo_id, Producto = grupo_id, Cantidad = cantidad. Sólo intento relacionar 2 columnas y es curioso que en el caso de grupo_id no haya tenido problemas.

Migración:

```
        Schema::create('pedidos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('producto_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('producto_id')->references('id')->on('productos');
            $table->string('miembro');
            $table->bigInteger('grupo_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('grupo_id')->references('id')->on('grupos');
            $table->integer('cantidad');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Mensaje de error:

Trying to get property 'producto' of non-object (View: /Users/eduardocoello/Projects/plenitud/resources/views/pedidos.blade.php)

Modelos

Producto:

```
    public function pedido()
    {
        $this->hasMany(Pedido::class);
    }
```

Pedido:

```
    public function producto()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Producto::class);
    }
```

Controlador de PedidosController, funciones.

```
    public function index()
    {
        $pedidos = Pedido::all();
        $grupos = Grupo::all();
        $productos = Producto::all();
        return view('/pedidos', compact('pedidos', 'grupos', 'productos'));
    }

        public function create()
    {
        $grupos = Grupo::all();
        $productos = Producto::all();
        return view('pedidos.crear', compact('grupos', 'productos'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $pedidos = new Pedido();
        $pedidos->producto_id = request('producto');
        $pedidos->miembro = request('miembro');
        $pedidos->grupo_id = request('grupo');
        $pedidos->cantidad = request('cantidad');

        $pedidos->save();
        return redirect('/pedidos');
    }
```

Comment: En principio, revisa como declaras las relaciones. La inversa de hasMany es belongsTo, pero estás poniendo las dos como hasMany. Por como es tu tabla pedidos, aparentemente un Pedido pertenece(belonsTo) a un Producto.

Comment: Por favor aclara el punto de ¿qué relación tienen ambas tablas?, por otro lado en tu foreach veo que tratas de acceder a una relación llamada `productos` pero la que esta declarada es `producto`

Comment: Hola @porloscerrosΨ, en esta parte se me complica ya que estoy acostumbrado a sólo usar INNER JOIN. Entonces, siguiendo tú respuesta, ¿el modelo de Pedido debería de incluir un belongsTo, debajo de la función de producto? Resultando en que: Un pedido le pertenece a un Producto, ¿es esto correcto? Gracias.

Comment: Hola @Aprendiz, la relación que tienen ambas es la siguiente. Para productos busco el nombre del producto, en otras palabras, buscamos la columna relacionada/asignada con el nombre de "producto", en este espacio se asigna el nombre o "string" de dicho "producto", y esta es la relación que busco imprimir (el error). Igual para grupos buscamos el nombre. 
$pedido->grupo->nombre
$pedido->productos->producto

Comment: Creo que a lo que vamos es si tu relación es: `1:1` o `1:N`

Comment: Bueno, eso no te lo puedo decir yo, pues no sé cuál es la lógica de negocio que quieres implementar en tu aplicación. Dinos tú si "UN Producto puede tener MUCHOS Pedidos" y "UN Pedido pertenece a UN(y solo UN) Producto". Una vez tengas claro eso, puedes definir las relaciones de Eloquent de acuerdo a la documentación, por ejemplo [Uno a Muchos](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many), donde verás que la [inversa](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) es belongsTo.

Comment: Si, así es, @Aprendiz. Para el caso de la tabla "pedidos" tenemos 2 columnas que buscan relaciones. Queremos relacionar la columna "grupo_id" con el id de la tabla y la columna "nombre", y en "productos" buscamos la relación con la columna "producto" y asociar el id dentro de esta tabla. ¿te suena esto correcto? Saludos.

Comment: Un pedido puede tener muchos productos @porloscerrosΨ, segun tu criterio, ¿cómo se desarrollaría mejor, según Laravel esta relación? Gracias.

Comment: Un producto "pudiera" en caso de ser así, tener inclusión en un pedido, 2 pedidos, o muchos pedidos. Entonces para que un producto pueda ser relacionado a un pedido, éste producto primero debe ser seleccionado y luego ser asociado a una entidad "pedidos"

Comment: Bueno entonces tu relación es 1:n Un pedido tiene muchos productos, entonces como ya te dijeron en el modelo Pedido debes tener un hasMany y en el modelo Producto un belongsTo, revisa el enlace que te han provisto

Comment: Ya fue solucionado, al parecer modificar lo que yo tenía como "Producto::class" y "Pedido:class", esto era incorrecto. Tenía que asociar el modelo y la columna dentro de la relación en mi modelo. Gracias.

Comment: Me pregunto si la relación dentro de mis modelos cambiaría si existe un pedido con varios productos. Por ejemplo que un pedido tenga 2 tipos de productos, 1 libro y 2 agendas. La relación, en base a lo discutido, como tendría que aparecer? Gracias.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo de lo que comentas, entonces "UN Producto puede tener Muchos Pedidos" y "Un Pedido puede tener Muchos Productos". Si es así, la relación sería [Muchos a Muchos](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) y necesitarías una tabla pivot para hacer la relación.

Comment: Estás en lo correcto @porloscerrosΨ, en cuanto a pedidos la relación es de muchos a muchos. ¿En qué consiste una tabla pivot?

Comment: La tabla pivot es un término mas de sql y no tanto en Laravel, en la cual almacenarás por ejemplo las llaves foráneas que vinculan a esta con sus respectivas tablas; me parece que mas que laravel debes definir bien que relaciones vas a manejar y en función de eso pases a Laravel; pues al momento al no tener esto clarificado estarás haciendo cambios constantes

Comment: Bueno entonces dime si esto te parece correcto. Tabla pivot tendría que tener 2 columnas "asociativas", producto_id, y pedido_id. Y que esta misma tabla pueda tener relaciones con ambas tablas; pedidos y productos. En cuanto a la función debería de crear un modelo exclusivo para la tabla "pivot" ?

Comment: La tabla está ok. No necesitas otro modelo, sólo define las relaciones en los modelos Pedido y Producto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Relación [Muchos a Muchos](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

#### Estructura de las tablas

Para definir esta relación, se necesitan tres tablas de base de datos: `productos`, `pedidos` y `pedido_producto`. La tabla `pedido_producto` se deriva del orden alfabético de los nombres de modelo relacionados y contiene las columnas `pedido_id` y `producto_id`:

**Migración productos:**

```
Schema::create('productos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    // las demás columnas
});
```

**Migración pedidos:**

```
Schema::create('pedidos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // $table->id(); // esto nunca lo ví y no sé si funcione, supongo que quieres una columna id autoincremental
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    // esta llave foránea no va aquí, la agregas en la tabla pivot
    // $table->bigInteger('producto_id')->unsigned();
    // $table->foreign('producto_id')->references('id')->on('productos');
    // las demás columnas
});
```

**Migración tabla de relación entre pedidos y productos:**

```
Schema::create('pedido_producto', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('pedido_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('pedido_id')->references('id')->on('pedidos');
    $table->bigInteger('producto_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('producto_id')->references('id')->on('productos');
});
```

#### Estructura del Modelo

Las relaciones de muchos a muchos se definen escribiendo un método que devuelve el resultado del método `belongToMany`. Por ejemplo, definamos el método de productos en nuestro modelo de Pedido:

```
/**
 * Los productos que pertenecen a un Pedido.
 */
public function productos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Producto::class);
}
```

Una vez que se define la relación, puedes acceder a los productos del pedido utilizando la propiedad dinámica de productos:

```
$pedido = Pedido::find(1);

foreach ($pedido->productos as $producto) {
    //
}
```

O en Blade, si estás iterando sobre una colección de Pedido:

```
@foreach($pedidos as $pedido)
    @foreach($pedido->productos as $producto)
        {{ $producto->id }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**Definiendo la inversa de la relación**

Para definir la inversa de una relación de muchos a muchos, realiza otra llamada a belongsToMany en tu modelo Producto.

```
/**
 * los pedidos que pertenecen a un Producto.
 */
public function pedidos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Pedido::class);
}
```

Y accedes de la siguiente manera:

```
$producto = Producto::find(1);

foreach ($producto->pedidos as $pedido) {
    //
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105815/discussion-on-answer-by-porloscerros--no-puedo-imprimir-un-dato-que-pertenece-a).